# VBA Code for copying and pasting data from one sheet to another based on column headers

Tags: vba, header, match, copy-paste

On sheet 1,in workbook1 cells A1:E1 have column headings, but no data. On sheet 1 of workbook2, the data range is A1: AC5000. I want to pick out the columns in this worksbook that match the headers on workbook1, copy and paste them under the column headers in workbook1. Can someone help me with this please

Comment: I'm new to VBA and hence asking questions that appear "poor" to someone quite skilled in VBA, but not to me

Comment: but you don't appear to have done any research or made much effort?

Comment: On the contrary, I have looked through these forums for the entire morning to find a code that will fi. but, none of them worked

Comment: This was the last attempt:

Comment: Dim header As Range, headers As Range
    Set headers = wsCopyFrom1.Range("A1:AR1")

    For Each header In headers
        If GetHeaderColumn(header.Value) > 0 Then
            Range(header.Offset(1, 0), header.End(xlDown)).Copy Destination:=wsCopyTo1a.Cells(2, GetHeaderColumn(header.Value))
        End If
    Next
End Sub

Function GetHeaderColumn(header As String) As Integer
    Dim headers As Range
    Set headers = wsCopyTo1a.Range("A1:E1")
    GetHeaderColumn = IIf(IsNumeric(Application.Match(header, headers, 0)), Application.Match(header, headers, 0), 0)
End Function

Comment: The code breaks at Set headers=wsCoptTo1a.Range("A1:E1") with a run time error 424 "Object required".

Comment: I have previously defined wsCopyTo1a

Comment: Can someone help, please

Answer (score 1):

Dim c As Range
Dim Rng As Range
Dim i As Integer

```
     Dim r As Range
     With wsCopyFrom1.Range("a1").CurrentRegion
     For Each r In wsCopyTo1a.Range("a1:g1")
      Set c = .Rows(1).Find(r.Value, , , xlWhole, , 0)
            If Not c Is Nothing Then
                .Columns(c.Column).Copy
                r.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

            End If
        Next
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
     End With
```

This works